# Any way to stop focussing a WPF textcontrol slowing application update performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing a C# WPF XAML-based Windows desktop application, and the UI is beautifully smooth and slick until I focus a textbox.  Once focussed, the update rate of the whole UI is much lower.   I'd estimate it all runs at the "full" (?) `60fps` originally, dropping to more like `30fps` after the text control gains focus.   I've dug around all sorts of Microsoft documentation and advice on WPF performance, but nothing seems to mention the mere act of a control gaining focus being a problem.  It's quite mystifying.  I've tried to use the Windows Performance Toolkit to analyse the issue, but I'm getting nowhere.  I've been able to do a klugey workaround in some scenarios with judicious use of `Keyboard.ClearFocus()` when clicking any other control, which returns the update rate to normal, but it's not great to have to do that.

This issue can be readily replicated - a brand new `VS2015` WPF project, with a text box and a button will show the issue (add `Keyboard.ClearFocus()` to the button's click handler).  This demonstrates it's nothing specific to my application code, it's a framework issue.

Does anyone have an idea why the described issue may be occurring, or how I may be able to resolve it?

**Update:** I've uploaded a sample project showing the issue, here: http://muuh.co.uk/SlowTextbox.zip

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this issue on other computers with different specs? I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: Post your solution somewhere, we could take a look.

Comment: cubrr: Yes, checked on several machines (Win7 and Win10).

Comment: John Peters: I've created a trivial minimal project and uploaded it as noted in my edited question.  Thanks.

Comment: I've looked at your sample but i don't see any appreciable difference between focus / non focus behavior. Your sample is pretty basic - are you seeing a real world difference in an actual app ?

Comment: auburg: Yes, a very noticeable effect.   The real app I'm developing feels very sluggish when the focus is in a textbox.   I think it's actually more noticable on a fast machine where the WPF UI normally reacts very smoothly indeed.  Perhaps I'll try and develop the simple example here to display the framerate to highlight the oddity.